# Flutter web, how do I make url change when pressing NavigationRail without pushing new Screen?

Tags: flutter, material-design

I want to implement NavBar that look like [material.io](https://m3.material.io/).

[image]

You can see that when click on NavigationRail, the contents and the url change, but NavigationRail stay consistently.

How to do this using [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router)?